# New line command on osx python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
print ("hello world", \n, "how are you")
```

I want the 2 separate strings to display on different lines, however this does not work on mac, where it works on pc. Is there a different command for mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your newlines command directly in the string for your prompt

```
print ("hello world\r\nhow are you")
```

and yes, the command is different on mac; it is \r\n

Answer (score 0):

That won't work even for Windows PCs as `\n` should be put in quotes:

```
print("Hello\nworld!")
```

Or `print("Hello","\n","world")` although I don't quite understand why you're splitting the string into three parts.